# What you do if there is a client ask you to work on project outside your specialization?

Tags: client-relations

For example,

You are a logo designer for more over 5 years.But someday, there is a client ask you to make 3D models through e-mail.Will you accept it??If you don't accept it, how  to say to him/her?

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. I'm not entirely sure I understand the point of your question. Are you proficient with 3D modelling? Is this a job you would be able to handle? If you're capable, why not? If you're not, it seems like the obvious choice is to decline the job

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you shouldn't accept the project if you can't do it.

...unless you have someone in your network willing to do this project with you and who also has the skills for it.

I also suggest you ask a bit more details to your client about the 3D modelling he/she wants. Sometimes clients misname stuff and maybe they're not really after 3D but something that "looks 3D."

---

The way to tell your client you can't accept this project is simply by saying that 3D modelling is a totally different path of design that requires an expertise you currently don't have. And because you respect their business, you prefer to be honest with them about this, so they can find someone who will be able to deliver the top quality they deserve for their project.

And if you can (and want), you can even offer to your client to help him/her find someone to do this work. Don't take the entire responsibility for this though but simply suggest them some good places where they might find someone who has the qualifications for the 3D modelling and maybe some keywords and tips to find a good candidate. Your clients will appreciate your honesty and the tips you can give them; most of the time, they don't even know where to get started and don't know what software are used for this, or where to look.

Don't forget to mention that you welcome any other project related to logo designs and that you'll be happy to help them with these ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common thing that occurs, don't worry, you'll have people asking you to build them websites and everything else too lol.  What you should do just for instances such as this is make sure you have relationships with people who do different things.  Depending on the project you could have someone who does 3D modeling take care of that part for you.  In reality a 2D version is going to have to be drawn out first to make into the 3D version so there's still a purpose for you to be involved.  Besides that I'm sure they'd want to have a simple 2D version as well for letterheads or stamps or whatnot.

My practice has always been if I can't do it, at least plug them directly into somebody who can because in the long run they know they can at least point them in the right direction if you can't do it yourself which makes you the best "starting point" in their mind, which will bring all sorts of opportunities through you.